# Vaadin TextArea font

Tags: textarea, vaadin

Is it possible to change the font of a TextArea?  I need a fixed-width font for displaying some raw data that is formmatted to display in columns in a console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with CSS, just create a theme for your application and add the following CSS to set a fixed-width font to all TextAreas in the application:

```
textarea.v-textarea {
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

Information about Vaadin themes can be found from [Book of Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/themes.html).

Comment: Using the same css code to set Monospace font to TextArea using textArea.addStyleName("textarea");  but on inspecting CSS in chrome, css setting v-textarea is getting overriden with default font. How do I fix this??Appreciate if you could help